# How to call a cmd on a remote server without having the absolute path

Tags: windows, script, batch-file

I would like to call a cmd (let's call it x.cmd) on a remote server. The x.cmd will return a log file in a log folder. Problem is this log folder in x.cmd doesn't have an absolute path (just a relative path like log\ ) so if I do

```
wmic /node:server process call create "serverpath\x.cmd"
```

it will process x.cmd but save the log file into `system32` or somewhere I assume. If I add `cd /d %~dp0` into x.cmd then it works fine.  Unfortunately I am not allowed to touch x.cmd. Just wondering is there any other way to call the x.cmd without modifying it and also the correct output. Thanks.

JS

Comment: If you have the path to x.cmd, why can't you use the server path and the relative path to the log folder to get what you want ?

Comment: Yes I can,the problem I　have now is nothing will be in that log folder as log folder path in x.cmd is not absolute. this is the previous question I　asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708633/batch-script-call-cmd-on-servers

Comment: If it is not absolute, then I am assuming it changes on every run. Is the path provided by the user when executing the x.cmd

Comment: so if I run it locally on that server it is fine, but cannot call it remotely. path is in x.cmd and given by the client so I am not allowed to touch it.

Comment: are you allowed to create a `.bat` file on the remote machine (and then delete it) only to get the absolute path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx

the second parameter that `wmic process` accepts is the directory.You can try this:

```
wmic /node:server process call create "serverpath\x.cmd" , "c:\path\to\x.cmd"
```

or

```
wmic /node:server process call create CommandLine="serverpath\x.cmd" CurrentDirectory="c:\path\to\x.cmd"
```

You might need one additional call of `net share` on the remote machine to get exact location of the directory. something like this:

```
wmic /node:server process call create "cmd /c \"net share ^> \\\\myshare\\server.shares.txt \""
```

Comment: process call create "cmd /c cd /d PATH_TO_X_CMD & PATH_TO_X_CMD\x.cmd" solved my problem! thanks everyone!